# useState hook - state gets lost i.e. resets to initial value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to initialize the state during the mounting cycle, and then do something with it on each update.

However, the state gets reset somehow? I don't understand why.

```js
const [journalItems, setJournalItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/journals/${props.match.params.key}/items`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setJournalItems(data)    // Sets the state when the AJAX completes
            })
        .catch(err => err);

    table.current = new Tabulator(refTable.current, {
        rowClick: function (e, row) {
            console.log("tabulator journalitems", journalItems) //  State is lost returns []
            handleTableRowClick(row._row.data.id)
        },
        columns: [
            { title: "Компанија", field: "companyName" },
            { title: "Документ", field: "documentKey" },
        ],
    });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect journalItems", journalItems)    // Works fine
    table.current.replaceData(journalItems)                // Uses the new state
}, [journalItems]);

function handleTableRowClick(journalItemId) {
    console.log("handletablerowclick journalitems", journalItems) // State is lost, resets to []
}
```

Results form the console logs...

```
useEffect journalItems []
useEffect journalItems (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

tabulator journalitems []
handleTableRowClick journalitems []
```

Comment: How many times do you see your console log? A `useEffect` with dependencies will actually still fire when the component mounts just like it does with `[]`. So I would expect to see one log with an empty array, and then a second if your update is successful.

Comment: Yes, I do see it twice. 1. `useEffect journalItems []`, 2. `useEffect journalItems (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`. However, the state in the click handler is empty...

Comment: Ok, your update makes the question clearer.

Comment: I am reading for a [possible solution here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often), but it makes no sense why this happens...

Comment: @Ivan , may be this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately . State change is asynchronous .

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Thanks for the suggestion. I managed to solve it, but it's very weird... Can you please check it and tell me if it's ok?

Comment: @BrianThompson Can you please check my answer? It works that way, but I am not sure if it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it in a weird way with `useRef` for the function variable, and by moving the function definition inside the `useEffect`?

```js
const [journalItems, setJournalItems] = useState([]);

let handleTableRowClick = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/journals/${props.match.params.key}/items`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setJournalItems(data)    // Sets the state when the AJAX completes
            })
        .catch(err => err);

    table.current = new Tabulator(refTable.current, {
        rowClick: function (e, row) {
            console.log("tabulator journalitems", journalItems) //  State is lost returns []
            handleTableRowClick.current(row._row.data.id)
        },
        columns: [
            { title: "Компанија", field: "companyName" },
            { title: "Документ", field: "documentKey" },
        ],
    });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect journalItems", journalItems)    // Works fine
    table.current.replaceData(journalItems)                // Uses the new state

    handleTableRowClick.current = (journalItemId) => {
        console.log("handletablerowclick journalItems", journalItems)
        // Find the clicked row from all the rows
        let journalItem = journalItems.filter(item => item.id === journalItemId)[0]
        setFormJournalItems(journalItem)
    }
}, [journalItems]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because the initial value for `journalItems` is being closed over inside the function defined for the `rowClick` property.

Because the effect containing the `table.current` is only run once, that `table.current` value gets all initial values and never gets updated with new handlers for the `rowClick` prop.

I suspect that you might need to make the changes below to get things moving along:

```
const [journalItems, setJournalItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/journals/${props.match.params.key}/items`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setJournalItems(data)    // Sets the state when the AJAX completes
            })
        .catch(err => err);
}, [props.match.params.key]);

// Re-create a new `table.current` value (including all handlers) when `journalItems` changes
table.current = useMemo(() => {
  return new Tabulator(refTable.current, {
        rowClick: function (e, row) {
            console.log("tabulator journalitems", journalItems)
            handleTableRowClick(row._row.data.id)
        },
        columns: [
            { title: "Компанија", field: "companyName" },
            { title: "Документ", field: "documentKey" },
        ],
    });
}, [journalItems]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect journalItems", journalItems) 
    table.current.replaceData(journalItems)              
}, [journalItems]);

const handleTableRowClick = useCallback((journalItemId) => {
  console.log("handletablerowclick journalitems", journalItems);
}, [journalItems]);
```

Don't forget to update the dependency array of your first effect. All variables from the outer scope that are referenced inside your effect must be in this array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please check my solution and comment on it? Which approach is better?